# How to add an entry into 'add/remove programs' for a .net windows app

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows

How to add an entry into 'add/remove programs' for a .net windows app?

Comment: "Create an installer with either WiX or a Visual Studio setup project" would be too obvious?

Answer (score 4):

Use a deployment project to create a MSI file and have the users execute that rather than xcopy deployment.

Answer (score 1):

ClickOnce deployment with option "Available online only" removed will also do this. Or create a MSI package.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to a deployment project, ClickOnce deployment will also achieve this.